# Scrollbar appears on the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I have a menu with some uls and content under it and I want that when I get the browser window bigger(CTRL +) the scrollbar that appears appears on the bottom of the page not under the menu.
I have the codes here (http://fiddle.jshell.net/MB3cF/) and as you can see in css I wrote

```
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:auto;
```

but the problem as you see in the website that the scrollbar appears under the menu exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: auto` causes that scroll bar under the menu. If you don't want that, then remove it and set a min-width on the menu (or, in a real-world situation, on the page content) to get the scroll bar to appear at the bottom of the browser window.

PS—it's not a great idea to wrap divs in `a`s. It is allowed in HTML5, but I would say only do it if you really need to (and it's not needed here).

EDIT: OK, as requested in the comments, here's a rough example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
body {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f8f8f8 url() repeat 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a {
    font-family:Helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid;
    border-color:#aaa #ccc;
    border-width:0 0 5px 6px;
    padding:6px 35px 7px 35px;
    margin:7px 15px;
    box-shadow:-1px 2px 5px #404040;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="">text here 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text here 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text here 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text here 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br>

    Some content

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see how it could works with min-width, it doesn't, can you please try to change some of the css codes here (http://fiddle.jshell.net/MB3cF/) so I can see what you are talking about?
BTW about your second point, What is the influence that wrapping divs in "a" does? and how it is not needed as I use it to autoscroll for the boxes of the contain? can you explain please because many people on stackoverflow told me this :(

Comment: OK, a rough example added above. For all of the history of HTML, until very recently with HTML5, it was not permitted to wrap an `<a>` around a block level element, like `<div>`. Even though is ti allowed in HTML5, don't do it unless there's a good reason—such as when you have a div full of elements and you want them all to be one big link to something else. Here, that's not needed at all. I changes your code to a real UL, also.

Comment: Wow man, you are the best! just one last problem I face, the menu's width isn't 100% as I can see.. it have to be exactly the same width as the screen width(0px from left 0px from top 0px from right) EVEN IF I zoomed in(CTRL +)

Comment: Can you please answer my question? Pleaseeee

Comment: OK, I've had another go at it and updated the code above. See if that's more like what you want.

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm looking for, unfortunately I have REAL problem that it's solution should be simple.
I can't use this codes without setting the menu as fixed position :( I REALLY need its position fixed neither it's useless, can you PLEASE fix that last problem, then I will upvote your answer and do whatever you want :-)

Comment: Did you try changing `absolute` to `fixed`? I'm not a bit fan of fixed, but in the example code above it doesn't matter which you use.

Comment: Also I can't use it with absolute position :(

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Can you show us what you are really trying to do? I'm in the dark.

Comment: it doesn't show scrollbar in the bottom of the page for the menu if position is fixed, if it's absolute it does.. I need it FIXED because I have to see the uls onscrolling(its style will be change onscroll and onpress it it will autoscroll)

Comment: Your code works GOOD AND VERY GOOD but without the fixed position and I need fixed position that's the problem

Comment: You aren't giving enough information. I'm in the dark here. I need to see what you are working on and get a clear indication of how you want the page to work.

Comment: Here's my webpage http://ge.tt/9jACz1h/v/0, I have a menu with some uls and content under it, try to ZOOM IN on the menu and you will see the scrollbar that appears on the bottom of the page, try to use it and you will see that it's NOT for the menu, I need the same scrollbar as that for the menu in the bottom of the page. IF you try to edit the page's code and set the position as absolute instead of fixed and try to zoom in it will be the same thing that I want but I don't want it absolute position I want it fixed, what I want works with absolute position but doesn't work with fixed, problem

Comment: First of all download the webpage, just press the "Download" word

Comment: Fixed position is in relation to the browser viewport, meaning that a fixed element won't move vertically or horizontally. So don't think you are going to have much luck here. At least I can't think of a solution.

Comment: but if you look for example at the facebook menu and try to zoom in you gets what I'm looking for even though its position is fixed :(

Comment: In Facebook, once the menu is wider than the viewport, alternate styles kick in to set it to `position: relative`, meaning that the menu is no longer fixed and doesn't stay on screen as you scroll down the page.

Comment: Facebook's menu STAYS in its position onscroll, definitely stays.
Go to facebook, log-in and try to scroll down and you can see that it stays in its position onscrolling so its position is fixed

Comment: You missed my point. Once you've zoomed in on Facebook, and the menu is too wide for the screen, that behavior ceases, and the menu switches to position: relative and no longer stays at the top of the page.

Comment: Oh I got your point now, can you give me a code for something like that? so when you zoom in the position of the menu turn to absolute..?

Comment: It's done with the help of JS, which adds an extra class to the body element. JS isn't my area, I'm afraid.